# How to convert Scala FilePart as File (Java) to use in multipart-form data?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, multipartform-data

I have a method that already have an FilePart[TemporaryFile] and i will call another method to send a multi-part form data. This method is using scala play 2.4.X and i have to send it using ning method below:

```
 def sendFile(file: FilePart[TemporaryFile]): Option[Future[Unit]] = {

   val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient = WS.client.underlying

   val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(s"${config.ocrProvider.host}")

   val multiPartPost = postBuilder
     .addBodyPart(new StringPart("access_token",s"${config.ocrProvider.accessToken}"))
     .addBodyPart(new StringPart("typename",s"${config.ocrProvider.typeName}"))
     .addBodyPart(new StringPart("action",s"${config.ocrProvider.actionUpload}"))
     .addBodyPart(new FilePart(**expects java.io.File not FilePart**)
 }
```

How can i take advantage of this parameter and send as java.io.File?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the content of `file: FilePart[TemporaryFile]` to disk and then use that file for constructing the new multipart request. You can see this example [Scala File Upload](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFileUpload)

```
val tempFile = new File("/tmp/some/path")
file.ref.moveTo(tempFile)
val filePart = new FilePart(tempFile)
```